# Can I create a site that controls access to unlisted YouTube videos?

Tags: video, youtube, privacy

I am creating a host website where users can upload their YouTube videos, which only users with adequate permissions can view.  I want my site to exclusively control the disclosure of videos, their metadata and even their URLs to the public. I want those videos to be invisible on YouTube, and hidden from Google spiders as well.

Unfortunately, I discovered that, with YouTube, a video can be shared freely by simply knowing its URL, which is easily obtained by studying the page source in the browser.

Can this backdoor be circumvented? Does YouTube have a feature that allows a video to be unlisted and locked, except if 'authorized' by another site?  If not, is there another video hosting site that does?

Comment: you can make a video private

Comment: This will not do what is required because the owner of the video would need to manually add permission to the other youtube users who have access. Also this can only be done for 50 users.